# How to unstack and grab multiple columns into index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'season': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                  'type': ['abc1', 'def1', 'abc1', 'def1'],
                  'metric1': [1, 1, 1, 1],
                  'metric_2': [2, 2, 2, 2],
                  'metric_3': [3, 3, 3, 3],
                  'metric_4': [4, 4, 4, 4]})
```

When I use `unstack` I would like it to grab the metric_n columns as `metric` and make it as index along with season and type, and for the metric values, give the column name `value`.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

```
----------------------------------------
|                             value |
| metric | season | type |
------------------------------------
| metric1 |   A   | abc1.|     1
                               1
                               1
                               1
| metric2 |.  B   | abc1.|     2
                               2
                               2
                               2
| metric3 |.  A.  | def1 |     3
                               3
                               3
                               3
| metric4 |   B.  | def1 |     4
                               4
                               4
                               4
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.melt` and set the index:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['season','type'], var_name='metric').set_index(['metric','season','type'])
df

Out[1]: 
                      value
metric   season type       
metric1  A      abc1      1
         B      def1      1
         A      abc1      1
         B      def1      1
metric_2 A      abc1      2
         B      def1      2
         A      abc1      2
         B      def1      2
metric_3 A      abc1      3
         B      def1      3
         A      abc1      3
         B      def1      3
metric_4 A      abc1      4
         B      def1      4
         A      abc1      4
         B      def1      4
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I didn't know this also exists in pandas. For some reason, I was unable to look for R melt equivalent in pandas. Thank you for saving many hours wasted!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using `stack()`:

```
In [2636]: df.set_index(['season','type']).stack().reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'level_2':'metric'}).set_index(['metric','season','type']).sort_index()
Out[2636]: 
                      value
metric   season type       
metric1  A      abc1      1
                abc1      1
         B      def1      1
                def1      1
metric_2 A      abc1      2
                abc1      2
         B      def1      2
                def1      2
metric_3 A      abc1      3
                abc1      3
         B      def1      3
                def1      3
metric_4 A      abc1      4
                abc1      4
         B      def1      4
                def1      4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['season','type'])
         .rename_axis(' metric', axis=1)
         .stack()
         .to_frame('value')
         .reorder_levels([2,0,1])
         .sort_index()
        )
print (df1)
                      value
 metric  season type       
metric1  A      abc1      1
                abc1      1
         B      def1      1
                def1      1
metric_2 A      abc1      2
                abc1      2
         B      def1      2
                def1      2
metric_3 A      abc1      3
                abc1      3
         B      def1      3
                def1      3
metric_4 A      abc1      4
                abc1      4
         B      def1      4
                def1      4
```